# How to Make Sessions and Login Credentials for every page in Asp.net with mysql database?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have done a Admin Web site Using `ASP.net, C#` with **MySQL** data Base

My website is Only designed for admin So that I have less users like 4-5..

But I made a Mistake that My Web Site Has 9 Pages in that
If I Copy and Paste the URL of a Page Its opening without login credential's and sessions..
So Please Suggest me for this kind. So that it should check authentication when ever a page is opened.

I am new to `asp.net` and I tried for this kind But I found Only for **SQL server** 
I want it For `ASP.net, C# with MySQL Data Base`

I don't want to use SQL-server as its commercial and expansive..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use master page... check credential in master page...

or else

1. you should pass credential to one page from another page(query string or cookie etc)
2. check credential in load method in all pages

http://dotnet.tekyt.info/?p=31
http://www.dotnetfunda.com/codes/show/4580/login-page-using-mysql-database
http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/04/30/creating-a-simple-registration-form-in-asp.net.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/438259/Insert-Update-Search-and-Delete-CRUD-operation-usi
http://www.mono-project.com/MySQL
http://www.mono-project.com/Database_Access
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/438259/Insert-Update-Search-and-Delete-CRUD-operation-usi

Comment: Thaks for Quick Responce Sir, I know the above Points, But How to Apply them in ASP.net,C# with MySQL can you Please Elaborate it, or some examples..

Comment: I don't know why you are talking about database? you can check credential with out database also... just create a class with user credential details and you can check it in each form loading, or else you should create a cookie with credential when a login is successfully completed, then you can check cookie in each form loaded, and important one, when you trying to logout, you must clear the cookie... that's it...

Comment: Yes fine But Admin may change time to time so we need to make different Credentials and i am asking Examples of that sir.. if u have Please help me,, You are just giving title of that when i search its going to SQL-server and those are not working...

Comment: Actually, What is your problem? do you know anything about sqlserver? few years ago i done project in same asp.net with sql server. i dont know why you are telling not working...

Comment: Ho,, sir i done many application.. i want to know it with mysql, i am asking reference links and i am not asking code.. i know about stack-overflow.. and i already mentioned `i don't want to use SQL-server..`

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/438259/Insert-Update-Search-and-Delete-CRUD-operation-usi
http://www.mono-project.com/MySQL
http://www.mono-project.com/Database_Access
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/438259/Insert-Update-Search-and-Delete-CRUD-operation-usi

Comment: Thanks thats wokrs fine sir,.. now this is a great answer.. I changed Complete SQL server contents to iss and database.. then its worked.. thank you sir...

Answer (score 0):

You can use web.config to deny access

```
<system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="admin" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
```

Comment: Thanks Artm sir, Its Giving a Error like "The Element authentication Has Invalid Child Element **allow**". List of Possible Elements expected : 'forms,passport' SO can you please suggest me on this.